# Using Base Navigation view for multiple views only reference the first one

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am working on a sencha touch mobile app, and I ham having a problem. I will try to include as much details as possible.

I have a TabPanel containing 2 items: home view and contact view.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
    requires: [
        'myapp.view.Home',
        'myapp.view.Contacts'
    ],

    config: {
        fullscreen : true,
        tabBar: {
            docked: 'bottom',
           defaults: {
                flex: 1
        },
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
            }

        },
        layout: {
            type: 'card',
            animation: {
                type: 'slide'
            }
        },
       items: [

            { xtype: 'homeView' },
            { xtype: 'contactsView' }

    ]
}
```

});

I want to have the same navigation view for each item. The navigation view has a button that push another view.

For that I have created a BaseNavigationView.js

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.BaseNavigationView', {
    extend : 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype : 'baseNavigationView',

    config : {
        navigationBar : {
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'My Info',
                align : 'right',
                id : 'myInfoButton',
                ui : 'small'
            }

            ]
        },
    }
});
```

And in the 2 views (Home and Contacts) I use

```
extend: 'myApp.view.BaseNavigationView'
```

In order to have the navigation view for both.

Until now everything is working fine.

Now for the controller, I want to add a tap event on the `MyInfo` button and push the `myInfoView` when tapped in the corresponding view.

In the controller I added to the Control section:

```
'#myInfoButton' : {
    tap : 'onMyInfoButton'
}
```

and the handler:

```
onMyInfoButton: function(self, e, eOpts) {
    //Create a new instance of the 
    if (!this.myInfoView) {
        this.myInfoView= Ext.create('myApp.view.myInfoView');
    }
    //Get the parent navigation view and push the view
    self.up('baseNavigationView').push(this.myInfoView);
}
```

When I run the application, Both the Home and Contact View are correctly showing the navigation view with the 'myInfoButton'.

**The problem**

When I click on the myInfoButton from the "Home" view, the "myInfoView" is pushed correctly with the back button.

However if I switch to the "Contacts" Tab and click on the myInfoButton , The "myInfoView" is pushed is Pushed in the "Home" tab and not the "Contacts" tab. so in the contacts tab nothing happens and I have to go back to the Home tab to see the pushed view.

So it is like `self.up('baseNavigationView')` is always referencing the navigation view of the Home and not the contact even when the button in the contact view is clicked.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks a lot for any help.